Sort results of DataView are different in different versions of .Net Framework
The GoodsNo column of the DataView has two pieces of data, HB3-T017 and HB-T015, which are now sorted by GoodsNo, with different results in .Net2.0 and 8.0.
The order under .Net2.0 is HB3-T017, HB-T015; while under .Net8.0 it is HB-T015, HB3-T017, I think the result under 8.0 is correct.
C# code：
create DataTable：
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("GoodsNo", typeof(string));

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["GoodsNo"] = "HB3-T017";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["GoodsNo"] = "HB-T015";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Sort by GoodsNo：
DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "", "GoodsNo", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

under .Net2.0 dv is：



GoodsNo




HB3-T017


HB-T015



under .Net8.0 dv is：



GoodsNo




HB-T015


HB3-T017



What are the reasons for the difference in results?

There's no such thing as ".NET 2.0". Do you mean .NET Framework 2.0 or .NET Core 2.0?

The following may be of interest: ASCII table.

thanks @jmcilhinney，it is .NET Framework 2.0 and 8.0.

I'm guessing it's sorted based on ASCII, but looking at the ASCII table, -(45) is smaller than 3(51), so HB-T015 should be ahead of HB3-T017, which is correct under .NET Framework 8.0, and I'm curious as to why it's not correct under .NET Framework 2.0. @user246821

There is no ".NET Framework 8". Naming wise, there was originally only .NET Framework and it went from version 1.0 to version 4.8.1. Along the way, they introduced .NET Core, which went from version 1.0 to version 3.1. The two were then merged in terms of functionality, although the new codebase was built on top of .NET Core, and the result was .NET 5 and later. The current version is .NET 8 with .NET 9 in preview.

I'm not sure whether this would be relevant when sorting a DataView but what is the value for Option Compare in the project properties for each?
